# Programatically detect if HDMI Monitor is switched off using ubuntu and PHP?

Tags: php, ubuntu, hdmi, xrandr

I have tried command using the following command:

```
xrandr | grep ' connected'
```

This command returns the list of port connected, how can i use this command to get only list of HDMI connected list.

Comment: xrandr -q no use here?

Comment: `xrandr | grep HDMI | grep ' connected'`

Comment: Also, you can add `| php` to use php